# How to test NSCFBoolean value?

Tags: objective-c

received data from JSON, which is looks like:

```
{
    myself = 1;
    "id" = 123;
}
```

and I put it into a NSDictionary *messageDic, I also defined a value *isMyself to receive the value of myself

```
Boolean isMyself = [messageDic objectForKey:@"myself"];
```

but it does not work.

So I print the date type,

```
const char* className = class_getName([[messageDic objectForKey:@"myself"] class]);
NSLog(@"yourObject is a: %s", className);
NSLog(@"Size of BOOL %d", sizeof(isMyself));
NSLog(@"Size of BOOL %@", [messageDic objectForKey:@"myself"]);
```

the results are:

```
2012-08-01 17:41:48.886  yourObject is a: __NSCFBoolean
2012-08-01 17:41:48.887  Size of BOOL 1
2012-08-01 17:41:48.887  Size of BOOL 0
```

and the if section below also does not work.

```
if ([messageDic objectForKey:@"myself"] == 0)
```

I tried

```
NSCFBoolean *isMyself = [messageDic objectForKey:@"myself"];
```

I got error form above.

my question is what should I do to test the value of `[messageDic objectForKey:@"myself"]`? and what is the `__NSCFBoolean`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 75, accepted):

the result you've got from [messageDic objectForKey:@"myself"], which is a NSNumber, then you need to convert the result to Bool. So try below:

```
if ([[messageDic objectForKey:@"myself"]boolValue] == NO)
```

Comment: Your mixing languages - boolValue is either YES or NO, so the above code should be '... == NO)

Comment: As @DavidH said, it is dangerous to use "== NO" on a BOOL

Answer (score 37):

__NSCFBoolean is a private class that is used in NSNumber [class cluster](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html). To extract appropriate value from it you need to use methods from NSNumber class, `-boolValue` in your case:

```
BOOL isMyself = [[messageDic objectForKey:@"myself"] boolValue];
```

Comment: Change that boolvalue to boolValue would ya?  I'm not permitted to make single char edits.