# Check for NSCFBoolean in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, boolean

I'm making a todo list app in iOS. I am storing the user's tasks in Firebase. When the task is completed I update a value in the database. When that value is read back in, I test it for a Bool, NSNumber and String due to some errors I ran into previously. Using type(of:), the value is getting read as "__NSCFBoolean", and my default case in a switch statement is running. How can I test for this type?

Sorry if this is a duplicate question, I could only find posts with NSCFBoolean in Objective-C.

This is my current code:

```
func observeForChildAdded(tableView: UITableView, snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
    let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String,Any>
    let taskIsCompleted = getIsCompletedSnapshotValue(snapshotValue: snapshotValue)
… 
}

func getIsCompletedSnapshotValue(snapshotValue: Dictionary<String,Any>) -> Bool {
    print(“Complete value : \(snapshotValue[“isCompleted”]!) : \(type(of: snapshotValue[“isCompleted”]!))”)

    if let isCompValue = snapshotValue[“isCompleted”]! as? Bool {
        return isCompValue
    } else if let isCompValue = snapshotValue[“isCompleted”]! as? Int {
        return (isCompValue == 1)
    } else if let isCompValue = snapshotValue[“isCompleted”]! as? String {
        return (isCompValue == “true”)
    }
    return false
}
```

observeForChildAdded() gets called whenever a child is added to the Firebase database.
It prints:
Complete value : 0 : __NSCFBoolean

Comment: “I test it for a Bool, NSNumber and String”—how do you test it? Edit your question to include the code.

Comment: `type(of:)` is very *objective-c-ish*. I guess there is a better native way.

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/11757008/5820010

Comment: Added the test code. Is there a better way to test for each type?

Comment: An `__NSCFBoolean` should always be castable to both `NSNumber` (as `__NSCFBoolean` is a private subclass of `NSNumber`) as well as `Bool` (due to bridging). Could you please provide a [mcve] of the issue you're facing?

Comment: Added the test function.

Comment: `snapshotValue` seems to be a `NS...` Foundation type. Cast it to a Swift type. This solves your problem.

Comment: @Vadian How would I do this? I have tried casting to Int but it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Your code seems to work as expected from what little we have.  To repeat Hamish's request, you need a minimal, complete example to get a useful answer.

Comment: From the given code `snapshotValue` is apparently `NSDictionary`. Cast it to `[String:Any]` which bridges all containing ObjC types to Swift types

Comment: Vadian, I tried as both an `NSMutableDictionary` and as `[String:Any]` both worked flawlessly.

Comment: @WillTaylor PS: As you obviously are responsible for the database you should save consistent data to avoid that kind of unnecessary type dance.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to iOS development and Firebase. How could I save consistent data?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Firebase but if there is a boolean type you should declare the field as Bool and save always a Bool. Then – as already mentioned – don't use `NS...`  Foundation collection types and conditional downcast the type to `Bool`.

Comment: How have you checked _my default case in a switch statement is running_? There's no switch statement in your code.

Comment: OOPer, it used to be a switch using type(Of:) but I changed to the if statement in the code above.

Comment: Then your code is running as expected, no?

Comment: It seems to be working now, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a standalone example that demonstrates that `__NSCFBoolean` can be cast as `Bool` or `Int`, but not as `String`:

```
let snapshotValue: [String : Any] = ["isCompleted": false as CFBoolean, "isCompleted2": true as CFBoolean]

print("snapshotValue[\"isCompleted\"] is of type \(type(of: snapshotValue["isCompleted"]!))")
print("snapshotValue[\"isCompleted2\"] is of type \(type(of: snapshotValue["isCompleted2"]!))")

if let b1 = snapshotValue["isCompleted"] as? Bool {
    print("isCompleted is \(b1)")
} else {
    print("isCompleted is not a Bool")
}

if let b2 = snapshotValue["isCompleted2"] as? Bool {
    print("isCompleted2 is \(b2)")
} else {
    print("isCompleted2 is not a Bool")
}

if let i1 = snapshotValue["isCompleted"] as? Int {
    print("isCompleted is \(i1)")
} else {
    print("isCompleted is not an Int")
}

if let i2 = snapshotValue["isCompleted2"] as? Int {
    print("isCompleted2 is \(i2)")
} else {
    print("isCompleted2 is not an Int")
}

if let s1 = snapshotValue["isCompleted"] as? String {
    print("isCompleted is \(s1)")
} else {
    print("isCompleted is not a String")
}

if let s2 = snapshotValue["isCompleted2"] as? String {
    print("isCompleted2 is \(s2)")
} else {
    print("isCompleted2 is not a String")
}

// Testing with a switch
switch snapshotValue["isCompleted"] {
case let b as Bool:
    print("it is a Bool with value \(b)")
case let i as Int:
    print("it is an Int with value \(i)")
case let s as String:
    print("it is a String with value \(s)")
default:
    print("is is something else")
}
```

**Output**

```
snapshotValue["isCompleted"] is of type __NSCFBoolean
snapshotValue["isCompleted2"] is of type __NSCFBoolean
isCompleted is false
isCompleted2 is true
isCompleted is 0
isCompleted2 is 1
isCompleted is not a String
isCompleted2 is not a String
it is a Bool with value false
```